# How to create this line with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to get this line but it's not work well, can someone help me.

[Image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2MfQ.jpg)

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Don't just provide a specification and expect code as a result.

Comment: it can be done with couple of div and css. But show us what have you tried to achive it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I can think of, is using a `svg`.
(scroll down when you run the code snippet to see the line or select full page)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision">
        <path d="M17.824773,139.979859h81.570997" transform="translate(.284592 0)" fill="none" stroke="#3f5787" stroke-width="0.6"/>
        <path d="M99.39577,139.979859c8.863476,0,5.210505-10.070493,15.865005-10.070493s171.446174,0,171.446174,0" fill="none" stroke="#3f5787" stroke-width="0.6"/>
        <ellipse rx="1.25" ry="1.227518" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1.018315 17.824773 139.979859)" fill="#090909" stroke-width="0"/>
</svg>
```

You can also style the `svg`s using CSS.